# Correct policy permissions for S3 bucket to allow specified users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket which contains business sensitive documents and images. I would like to be able to grant all actions and permissions to the root AWS user and another user that I have created. However, I want to restrict all access to anyone else, including getting objects by anonymous users.

I am able to use the created user's access keys to create objects in the bucket but it seems that these objects are viewable to anyone. For example, a GET request from an incognito browser session to an image object will get a 200 and not a 403 as expected.

Below is the bucket policy I am using, with sensitive details changed.

```
{
    "Version": "2016-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1487090751111",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1487090741111",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789876:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789876:user/my_user"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check the object ACLs.  An object can be `public-read`.  If you click on the object link in the console, then the `Properties` tab, you'll see that `Everyone` has `Object access` set to `Read`.  If this is true, then the object can be downloaded by anyone unless this is changed or there is a `Deny` in the bucket policy.

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: I'm unsure at this moment but I think it very likely.